# Selenium WebDriver ошибка при запуске в Codeception (Yii2)

Tags: php, yii2, selenium, selenium-webdriver, codeception

Работаю с Yii2. Только начинаю изучать написание тестов. Установил Codeception. Пробую запустить приемочный тест, но падаю с ошибкой:

> In WebDriverException.php line 106:
>
> POST
>   /session/dac1b4f2-ee4d-4692-80f2-ae2da2cf287b/timeouts/implicit_wait
>   did not match a known command
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time:
>   '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
>   System info: host: 'alexchep-ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name:
>   'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-139-generic',
>   java.version:  '1.8.0_191'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown

В качестве сервера пробовал как чистый Selenium, так и WebDriver Manager(Selenium с уже готовыми драйверами для chrome и firefox).

Если использовать просто PhpBrowser, то все работает, тест проходит. А если включаю WebDriver, то firefox(chrome) запускается, но не переходит по url, а просто висит открытым и при этом в консоль проливается ошибка(которая выше).

Вот конфиг моего acceptence.suite.yml:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
   enabled:
#      - PhpBrowser
       - \Helper\Acceptance
       - WebDriver

   config:
#      PhpBrowser:
#      url: http://swiftfull.ll/
       WebDriver:
          url: http://swiftfull.ll/
          browser: firefox
          restart: true
          window_size: 1024x768
```

Хожу к себе на локальную машину. Пробовал отдельно ставить драйвера для хрома и мозилы, не помогло. Я понимаю, что скорее всего что-то с драйверами судя по ошибке, но уже прошурстел гугл вдоль и в поперек и не смог найти решение. Возможно я что-то упускаю, может кто уже сталкивался с подобной ситуацией. буду благодарен за любую помощь, совет. Спасибо.